# Big integer type in Q

Tags: kdb

long isn't "long" enough to store the numbers / calculations I do.

I tried to solve problem 16 from project euler:
https://projecteuler.net/problem=16

but I couldn't, because 2^63 is getting bigger than long can store

```
q)prod2: {[y] (y-1) {x*2}/ 2}
q)prod2(63)
0N
q)prod2(62)
4611686018427387904
```

(i need to calculate `prod2(1000)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not store number that big in long datatype as it is beyond its limit. There are 2 choices:

A) Implement your logic in other language which supports big integers like Java and call that code in your KDB process.

B) If you want to implement this in KDB then you will have to use other data structures like  vector or string to store big number.

For example to represent 2^62 in boolean vector:

```
q) 1b,62#0b
```

Read about algorithms to calculate integer powers and implement one of those. There are also algorithms which works on binary representation.

You can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring